# Jasmine - what connects a source to spec file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, jasmine

Just getting started with Jasmine. I understand you put (like Rspec) the spec file in the `javascripts` folder with a naming convention of `<file_name_to_be_tested>_spec.js`

That's great!

So I have `spec/javascripts/orders_new_spec.js`

I've discovered that I can use the above to test EITHER of the files below:

```
app/assets/javascripts/orders/new.js
app/assets/javascripts/orders_new.js
```

But for someone like me who does have a somewhat complex file directory... I need a way to differentiate the two... Right now of course the `jasmine.yml` looks like this:

```
src_files:
  - assets/orders/new.js
  - assets/orders_new.js
```

But since there's ONE yml file for all specs, it doesn't serve as a differentiator.

Is there some way to, in the spec file itself do it? E.g.,

```
# /spec/javascripts/orders/new_spec.js
require 'assets/orders/new.js` # and ignore jasmine.yml
describe...

# /spec/javascripts/orders_new_spec.js
require 'assets/orders_new.js` # and ignore jasmine.yml
describe...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formal answer is no. Of course there are ways of hacking around it. From the Jasmine Github mods:

Jasmine (especially in the browser) doesn't have any relationships between which spec file tests which implementation file. If you have a subset of files that can't be loaded in the same page as some other subset of files, you probably want to have multiple `jasmine.yml` files and use the `JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable to pick the right one when running your tests. This would mean you need to run two (or more) `jasmine:ci` tasks to run all of your specs.

The other option would be to refactor/rework your implementations so that all of the files can be loaded into the browser at the same time and just instantiate the underlying objects in your specs.